# can't get Object when it is Selected

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

### File: ServiceAnnonce.java

```
  public List<Annonce> loadAnnonce( UserEntity idUser ) {
    Query query = getEntityManger().createQuery( "select u from "
            + getPersistentClass().getSimpleName()
            + " u where u.annonceUser= :idUser" ).setParameter( "idUser", idUser );
    List<Annonce> annonce = (List) query.getResultList();
    return annonce;
}
```

File : DaoUser.java

```
public UserEntity loadUserByEmail( String email ) {
    Assert.notNull( email );
    UserEntity user = null;
    Query query = getEntityManger().createQuery( "select u from "
            + getPersistentClass().getSimpleName()
            + " u where u.email= :email" ).setParameter( "email", email );
    try {
        user = (UserEntity) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch ( NoResultException e ) {

    }
    return user;
}
```

### File : ServiceUser.java

```
public Annonce annonceEnFonctionId( Annonce annonce, String email ) {

    UserEntity user = userDao.loadUserByEmail( email );
    List<Annonce> a = annonceDao.loadAnnonce( user );

    Annonce an = annonce;

    for ( int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) {
        if ( a.get( i ).getId() == (Long) an.getId() ) {

              an = annonce;
        }

    }

    return an;
}
```

### File: flow.xml

```
<transition on="annonceID" to="annonceEnFonctionId">
        <evaluate expression="userService.annonceEnFonctionId(annonce,user.getEmail())" result="flowScope.annonce" />
    </transition>
```

### File : OurAnnonce.java

```
    <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{annonce}">

        <p:column style="width:2%">
        <h:commandButton value="show" action="annonceID" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.titre}" />                          
        </p:column>
```

### File:shwo.java

```
<p:dataTable var="valeur" value="#{annonce}">
        <p:column headerText="Model">
            <h:outputText value="#{valeur.titre}" />
        </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

when i click Button show i should get more detail of annonce selected but i still get always the first annonce in DataBase any idea  ??

Comment: What you are expected to get if your annonceEnFonctionId method return only one object ? and your loadAnnonceById method use getSingleResult method that return only one object instead of list of announce's object

Comment: loadAnnonceByID should return List that what you mean ??

Comment: Exactly, let your loadAnnonceByID method a list of announce

Comment: but even when i do that i get the same result

Comment: Check the count of objects returns from announceDao.loadAnnounce and before you make that stranger filter

Comment: i do it before and i get two object like in DataBase

Comment: Good, so the problem now is not in dao nor service, but in that for loop that return only one object

Comment: i access to the loop but i get the first line in DataBase

Comment: Why does announceEnfonctionId have return Announce and not List of Announces .

Comment: i need to get one Object when it is selected

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking people to debug code without showing the minimum effort to at least reduce the problem.